# Kafka Connect with Mysql using Kafka with version 2.12-2.4.1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am completely new to Kafka, trying to get the data from Mysql using Kafka, For that I have used two jars kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.1 and mysql-connector-java-8.0.17 kept inside the lib folder of Kafka
(Path: ....\kafka_2.12-2.4.1\libs), I am using Windows10 with java-8.

I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7LUbtOFcQI

Once I start the connector getting below issue. Any solutions will be appreciated.

```
E:\2020\kafka_2.12-2.4.1>.\bin\windows\connect-distributed.bat .\config\connect-distributed.properties
[2020-04-30 17:46:49,773] WARN could not get type for name org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:428)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 10 more
[2020-04-30 17:46:49,837] WARN could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:428)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:263)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:204)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
        ... 10 more
[2020-04-30 17:46:49,848] WARN could not get type for name io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifier from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifier
```

The post request I am sending

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_03",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user",
        "connection.user": "root",
        "connection.password": "root",
        "topic.prefix": "mysql-02-",
        "table.whitelist": "test",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name": "id",
        "poll.interval.ms": "1000",
        "timestamp.column.name": "modified",
        "tasks.max": "2",
        "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_03"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
```

Comment: You're better off following the proper installation docs, or better using `confluent-hub` (hub.confluent.io) to install the connector for you.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I am able to produce and consume by creating topics using same Kafka setup, but KafkaConnect is not working, Is any changes need to be done in connect-distributed.properties? or any solution will be available for this issue.. I tried it with different version of Kafka-connect jdbc 5.4 git same issue

Comment: The Class error indicates the JARs haven't been installed correctly. Instead of dropped files in you're better off installing it properly.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/installation/docker/docs/installation/connect-avro-jdbc.html

Comment: I am able to run the connector by changing the version mysql-connector-java- to 5  , still warning will come in windows but it is running, In Linux it is working fine without above issue, But I am not not able to fetch the tables, getting warning " WARN No tasks will be run because no tables were found (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector)"  , In both Linux and Windows getting this warning message
I have added the POST request I am sending, in the discription

Comment: i'm having the same issue with postgress  WARN No tasks will be run because no tables were found (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector). have you been able to resolve it?